# How to pass runtime query parameter(native query) to RepositoryItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want to search the fail events based on transaction-datetime. I want to provide this transcation-date at start of each execution cycle. i.e for all batches in same cycle it should remain same.

```
public RepositoryItemReader<EventData> defineReader() {
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortMap = new HashMap<>();
    sortMap.put("id", Sort.Direction.ASC);

    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<EventData>()
            .repository(eventsDataRepository)
            .methodName("findEventsByStatus")
            .arguments(Arrays.asList(OffsetDateTime.now()))
            .saveState(false)
            .sorts(sortMap)
            .pageSize(3)
            .build();
}


@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM eventsdata et where et.created_on < ?1and et.status = 'fail' " ,  
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM eventsdata et where et.created_on < ?1 and and 
    et.status = 'fail' ",
    nativeQuery = true) 
Pageable<Event> findEventsByStatus(OffsetDateTime transcation, Pageable pageable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a step-scoped reader and configure it with the dynamic time. For example, if you pass the time as a job parameter, you can do something like the following:

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemReader<EventData> defineReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['time']}") String time) {
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortMap = new HashMap<>();
    sortMap.put("id", Sort.Direction.ASC);

    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<EventData>()
            .repository(eventsDataRepository)
            .methodName("findEventsByStatus")
            .arguments(Arrays.asList(OffsetDateTime.parse(time)))
            .saveState(false)
            .sorts(sortMap)
            .pageSize(3)
            .build();
}
```